# Kubernetes service not accessible on IPv4

Tags: service, kubernetes, ip, kubernetes-service

we currently have following Kubernetes setup (v1.13.1, setup with `kubeadm`) with connectivity set up between them:

- Master node (bare metal)
- 5 worker nodes (bare metal)
- 2 worker nodes (cloud)
- There is no proxy in between to access cluster, currently we are accessing services via `hostname:NodePort`

We are experiencing issue with accessing services via `NodePort` on 2 cloud worker nodes. What is happening is that service is accessible via IPv6, but not via IPv4:

- IPv6:
  telnet localhost6 30005
  Trying ::1...
  Connected to localhost6.
  Escape character is '^]'.
- IPv4:
  telnet localhost4 30005
  Trying 127.0.0.1...

Thing is that both are working on bare metal nodes. If I use `netstat -napl | grep 30005`, I can see `kube-proxy` is listening on this port (`tcp6`). I presumed this means that it does not listen on `tcp`, but aparently this is not the case (I have same picture on bare metal worker nodes):

```
tcp6       7      0 :::30005                :::*                    LISTEN      24658/kube-proxy
```

I have also read that services are using IPv6, but based on bare metal worker nodes, it seems there should not be a problem using IPv4 there as well.

Any idea what would cause that issue and how to solve it?

Thank you and best regards,
Bostjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles upon same issue, there was issue with unopened ports on FW for `flannel` network overlay:

- `8285 UDP` - flannel UDP backend
- `8472 UDP` - flannel vxlan backend